# Trying to Understand Access Modifiers in Java

Tags: java, object, inheritance

Just had a question regarding access modifiers in Java. So i thought that default methods cannot be inherited by a class, unless in the same directory but how come "myfunc()" gets inherited in this file.

```java
package com.daniel.oops.poly;

import com.daniel.oops.poly2.B;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A bobject = new B();
        bobject.myfunc();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.daniel.oops.poly;

public class A {
    void myfunc() {
        System.out.println("Default function");
    }
}
```

```java
package com.daniel.oops.poly2;

import com.daniel.oops.poly.A;

public class B extends A {

}
```

Comment: _"default methods"_?

Comment: If you're asking why `Main` can call `myfunc`, which is declared in class `A`, it's because `Main` and `A` are in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Well `Main` and `A.myfunc()` are in the same package, so I think `myfunc()` is just visible because package private means exactly that.

Comment: Perfect, I think I got it now! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a table that might help you understand why it works like that.

```
Modifier    Class   Package     Subclass    World
public        Y        Y            Y         Y
protected     Y        Y            Y         N
no modifier   Y        Y            N         N
private       Y        N            N         N
```

Comment: Perfect, I think I got it now! I appreciate the help!